# Android OOM errors due to image cacheing?

Tags: android, memory

It will be a little easier to understand this if you think if the app I'm working on like facebook (at least that will give you a context for what i'm doing).  I have one activity that uses a navigationdrawer to swap between fragments each of these fragments could have from one to several "subFragments" --- think of these as individual posts with things like a textview, a few buttons and an ImageView in them.  When the "container fragment" is created I call to the server and get the data I need to make all the "sub fragments".  I then iterate through the data and add all the "sub fragments" to the "container fragment"'s view.

I have noticed that I seem to be using an excessively high amount of memory (around 129 mb).

When the subfragments are created I then call this async task which pulls the images each fragment will need from a server and places them in their ImageView.

```
public class URLImageFactory extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap>
{
    ImageView imgView;
    private static final ImgCache mCache = new ImgCache();

    public URLImageFactory(ImageView bmImage) {
        this.imgView = bmImage;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
        String urldisplay = Config.SERVER_URL + urls[0].replaceAll("\\s+","%20");

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        //If it is in the cache don't bother pulling it from the server
        if(bitmap != null)
        {
            return bitmap;
        }

        try {
            InputStream in = new java.net.URL(urldisplay).openStream();
            //This is in case we are using match_parent/wrap content
            if(imgView.getWidth() == 0 || imgView.getHeight() == 0)
            {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            } else {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in),
                        imgView.getWidth(), imgView.getHeight(), false);
            }
            mCache.put(urldisplay,bitmap);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        imgView.setImageBitmap(result);
    }
}
```

I have made a rudimentary attempt at caching the images to speed up the process

public class ImgCache extends LruCache {

```
    public ImgCache() {
        super( calculateCacheSize() );
    }

    public static int calculateCacheSize()
    {
        int maxMemory = (int) Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory() / 8;
        int cacheSize = maxMemory;
        return cacheSize;
    }

    @Override
    protected int sizeOf( String key, Bitmap value ) {
        return value.getByteCount() / 1024;
    }
}
```

My app is crashing with outOfMemory exception.  I have also noticed that when my "container fragment" is swapped out for a different one ... usually a similarly structured fragment... the onPause() and onStop() of these sub fragments are not being fired.  If it helps the sub fragments are static inner classes while the container fragment is not. I think it is a bitmap related issue, but I'm not sure.  I have attempted to use TransactionManager.remove(fragment) on all the sub fragments when the parent hits onPause but it doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Have you tried using the eclipse memory analyzer to see which objects are taking memory in your app? Also, to point out `Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory()` tells you the number of bytes. Why do you divide it by 8?

Comment: I divided it by 8 because I figured 1/8th of the memory was appropriate for cache... was more of a guess

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that every time it adds a bitmap into the UI it spits out Grow heap (frag case) to ####

Comment: At this point it will all be speculation, I would recommend using MAT (memory analyser tool) to see what are the objects in your app that are using memory. It is high chance it is bitmap but you need to validate that.

Comment: Here is a good article on how to use MAT, http://macgyverdev.blogspot.com/2011/11/android-track-down-memory-leaks.html

Answer (score 2):

You're dividing the byte count of each object by 1024, but only dividing the available memory by 8; the result is that the LRU cache could fill up to 128 times the amount of available memory you have. Remove the `/ 1024` from `sizeOf` and you should be good.